# How to execute another project within the same solution?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I have few projects in my solution explorer that I want to build sequentially as shown in the below figure.
[image]

The buildserver Project here is trying to build a .dll. I want this project to be executed from the testExecutive project. How do I go about doing this?

I tried adding build dependencies and also added {using Buildserver} in my testExecutive.cs file. But when I click run only the testexecutive project runs, not the buildserver.

Can I programmatically command another project to build?

Comment: You seem to be using "execute" and "build" interchangeably. Do you want to programmatically **build** a project, or just have Visual Studio build everything and have one project call into another at runtime?

Comment: @BarmakShemirani But the Build server project generates a .dll as output and visual studio says that some other project that generates a .exe must be the startup project.

Comment: You can't just "execute" a dll. There's no standard entry-point for a dll. Maybe this project should be an executable instead of a dll. Either that or explicitly call the function you want from the testExecutive project.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read the whole post. My comment was totally useless.

Comment: @blorgbeard  I want to call the build server project from the test executive project and ask the build server to build itself.

Comment: How is the build server going to "build itself"? I don't understand what you mean by that.

Answer (score 2):

Build dependency only ensures that project you specified in the dependencies section (BuildServer) is built before the dependent project (testExecutive) when you build the whole solution.

If you want to run some action before the build of a specific project, there is a "Build Events" section in the project properties where you can execute any command prior to the build if you specify it in "Pre-build event command line".
To achieve what you described, you could enter here:

```
MSBuild ..\BuildServer\BuildServer.csproj /verbosity:minimal /target:Rebuild
```

But I would not recommend that, because that will build it twice when you rebuild the whole solution.

You could maybe define it to work like that only for debug mode:

```
if $(ConfigurationName) == Debug MSBuild ..\BuildServer\BuildServer.csproj /verbosity:minimal /target:Rebuild
```

make sure that the csproj path is correct and msbuild.exe is in your environment variable path.

But all this seems unnecessary to me. You can just right click your BuildServer project and select build any time after you update any code there. Or just build the whole solution with F6. Project dependency will ensure that BuildServer is built before testExecutive project.